# Grouping and summarizing data into a new pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the below (my actual dataframe is around 200k rows).  Each row is a unique user's distance from the origin point and the time since they logged in last.

```
+------------+------------------+
| time_since | dist_from_origin |
+------------+------------------+
|          1 | 0.12             |
|          0 | 71.15            |
|          4 | 74.48            |
|          2 | 19.69            |
|          3 | 0.12             |
|          0 | 132.92           |
|          1 | 174.45           |
|          4 | 0.12             |
|          3 | 81.07            |
|          2 | 65.43            |
|          1 | 162.58           |
|          0 | 0.12             |
|          3 | 0.12             |
|          4 | 20.68            |
|          3 | 109.93           |
|          2 | 100.87           |
|          0 | 131.50           |
|          0 | 132.74           |
|          4 | 181.35           |
|          3 | 150.55           |
+------------+------------------+
```

I would like to create a new dataframe which summarizes the data like the example below.  Where column 1 is the number of days inactive, column two is the count of users (rows?) in the group and each following column is a count of the distances that fit into that particular criteria.

```
+---------------+-----------+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| days inactive | num users | <=5 | >5 and <=25 | >25 and <=50 | >50 and <=100 | >100 and <=150 | >150 and <=225 |
+---------------+-----------+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|             0 |         5 |   1 |           0 |            0 |             1 |              3 |              0 |
|             1 |         3 |   1 |           0 |            0 |             0 |              0 |              2 |
|             2 |         3 |   0 |           1 |            0 |             1 |              1 |              0 |
|             3 |         5 |   2 |           0 |            0 |             1 |              1 |              1 |
|             4 |         4 |   1 |           1 |            0 |             1 |              0 |              1 |
+---------------+-----------+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I tried to accomplish the summary dataframe by looping through the groups in a groupby object, where the object was grouped by `time since` but I had some difficulty creating the summaries for each group and appending to a new data frame.

For example. I am hitting errors with one of the first steps: counting the rows in each group:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df['time_since'])

for group in grouped:
    print group['time_since'].count()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-2182867bdacc> in <module>()
      1 for group in grouped:
----> 2     print group['time_since'].count()

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

I was thinking another option would be to create boolean masks for each of my cases and then summarize each mask.

What I'm asking is, what is the simplest way to go from my original dataframe to the summary dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

Create your `BINS`

```
In [144]: BINS = [0,5,25,50,100,150,225]
```

Then, group by on `'time_since'` and buckets `pd.cut(df['dist_from_origin'], BINS)]`

```
In [145]: (df.groupby(['time_since', pd.cut(df['dist_from_origin'], BINS)])
              .size().unstack('dist_from_origin').fillna(0))
Out[145]:
dist_from_origin  (0, 5]  (100, 150]  (150, 225]  (5, 25]  (50, 100]
time_since
0                      1           3           0        0          1
1                      1           0           2        0          0
2                      0           1           0        1          1
3                      2           1           1        0          1
4                      1           0           1        1          1
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but it seems to be skipping over non-unique rows.  For example (verified in excel), I have several rows in the `day 0` `time_since` bucket that have the same distance.  Is there any way to count all rows that match the criteria, not just unique rows?

Comment: Ah, it counts all the records. I quite don't follow `skipping over non-unique rows`. In the exmaple data you provided of 20 rows, and the buckets have a sum of 20 as it should.

Comment: Oops, sorry!  I meant that I tried this on my 200k row dataset in excel and and the count of <5 bin using your code differs from what I am getting in excel, all of the other column bins match however.  Is there some reasoning why only the `0,5` bin would differ between my excel work and your code?

Comment: Are there records where `dist_from_origin` equals `0` ? check with `BINS=[-1,5,25,50,100,150,225]`

Comment: @JohnGalt Yes, and the number of records is exactly the difference that I am seeing!

Comment: @JohnGalt Just curious, why do I need to use `-1` in `BINS` to match the zero values

Comment: `(0, 5]` includes 5 but not 0, -- called as  half-open bins

Comment: `pd.cut(df['dist_from_origin'], BINS, right=False)` for half-bins with the leftmost edge included.